# How to use v-for with a Range and add additional input using push()

Tags: vue.js, multidimensional-array

How to use the `v-for` with a range. My starting point would have a 5 value and this is my sample.

```
<td v-for="(n,index) in 5" :key="index">
    <input v-model="form.overAllScores[n]" class="quiz d-flex"/>
</td>
```

But my problem is, how can i add additional items using the `push` method with the same `data` name of `overAllScores` and this is **2D array**

Here i inputted the scores.
[image]

Comment: Can't you initialize `form.overAllScores` to size 5 and then just `v-for` over that array?

Comment: @user2718281, thanks just haven't thought of initializing my data to give a value. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    count: 5,
    form:{
    overAllScores:['','','','','']
    }
  },
  methods: {
   add(){
     let len = this.form.overAllScores.length
     this.$set(this.form.overAllScores, len, '')
      this.count++
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="(item,n) in count">
      <input v-model="form.overAllScores[n]">
    </li>
  </ol>
  <button @click="add">add</button>
  <div>
  {{JSON.stringify(form.overAllScores)}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. this works perfectly. my bad the `overAllScores` should be an object and not array. but thanks